# How to vocalize hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: terminology

When I want to vocalize a hexadecimal number like 0x41, so I say "forty one in hexadecimal", "four, one in hex" or what? Or do you always have to calculate and say "65 in hexadecimal notation"? I feel like that would complicate communication if I just want to tell someone what numbers I see on the paper in fornt of me, so he can write them down for example.

Comment: I would say `0x41` as "four one, in hexadecimal". Because if I said for example `0xd5`, I would say "dee five, in hex".

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52494/how-do-you-pronounce-numbers-written-in-different-bases

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65760/how-do-you-say-10-when-its-in-binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to read out the digits and then say "hex(adecimal)". Don't say "forty-one hex" because "forty" means four times ten, whereas the four in 41h stands for four times sixteen. Don't say "sixty-five in hex" because then the person you're talking to doesn't know if you mean "The decimal number sixty-five, only written out in hex, i.e., four-one-hex" or "The number six-five-hex, i.e., one hundred and five decimal."